# How to run a linear regression on estimated coefficients

Tags: r, linear-regression

Consider the following:

```
a <- c( 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 100, 11)
b <- c(5, 6, 7, 80, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14)
c <- c(15, 16, 175, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24)

x <- c(17,18,50,15,64,15,3,5,6,9)
y <- c(55,66,99,83,64,51,23,64,89,101)
z <- c(98,78,56,21,45,34,61,98,45,64)

abc <- data.frame(cbind(a,b,c))
```

Firstly, I plan to run a regression and values abc with xyz as follows (This went according to plan):

```
dep_vars <- as.matrix(abc)
lm <- lm(dep_vars ~ x + y + z, data = abc)
```

From here, I understand that we can print the summary in the console using either of these two methods:

```
summary(lm)

map_dfr(summary(lm), tidy, .id = 'dep_var')
```

My issue is that I would like to run a regression of the coefficients of x, y and z on a, b and c.

Comment: It isn't clear to me what the problem you are having is.

Comment: I don't have an idea of how to access the coefficients for my second regression. I will edit the question to make it more clear.

Comment: Do you just want `coef(lm)`?

Comment: Yes. Thanks for that! Didn't think it was that simple

Comment: See the “predict()” function.

Answer (score 0):

#### Base R Options

The others have already answered your question, but I felt like providing multiple options in case you wished to know them for the future. Here, all of these base R functions do effectively the same thing albeit in slightly different ways:

```
#### Call Directly From Saved LM Object ####
coef(lm)
lm$coefficients # functionally equivalent to above
lm[1] # returns vector format from list
```

For example `lm$coefficients` and `coef(lm)` both look like this:

```
                     a          b           c
(Intercept) 15.3706338 44.2597407 -51.0505560
x           -0.5862903 -0.3488530   1.0575465
y            0.4074877  0.1587221   0.7602451
z           -0.2724661 -0.5257350   0.2025181
```

Whereas pulling it from a saved `lm` object gives you a vectorized version pulled from a list:

```
$coefficients
                     a          b           c
(Intercept) 15.3706338 44.2597407 -51.0505560
x           -0.5862903 -0.3488530   1.0575465
y            0.4074877  0.1587221   0.7602451
z           -0.2724661 -0.5257350   0.2025181
```

#### Broom/Dplyr Options

If you want a tidy version of this, `tidy` transforms a base R `lm` object into a tidier format that you can directly manipulate:

```
#### Broom and Dplyr ####
library(tidyverse)
library(broom)

tidy(lm) # pull all terms
```

Like so:

```
# A tibble: 12 × 6
   response term        estimate std.error statistic p.value
   <chr>    <chr>          <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>   <dbl>
 1 a        (Intercept)   15.4      45.8       0.335   0.749
 2 a        x             -0.586     0.538    -1.09    0.318
 3 a        y              0.407     0.454     0.898   0.404
 4 a        z             -0.272     0.426    -0.639   0.546
 5 b        (Intercept)   44.3      30.4       1.46    0.195
 6 b        x             -0.349     0.357    -0.978   0.366
 7 b        y              0.159     0.300     0.528   0.616
 8 b        z             -0.526     0.282    -1.86    0.112
 9 c        (Intercept)  -51.1      69.1      -0.739   0.488
10 c        x              1.06      0.812     1.30    0.240
11 c        y              0.760     0.684     1.11    0.309
12 c        z              0.203     0.643     0.315   0.763
```

To select some specific coefficients, you can simply add `slice` to whatever you please:

```
tidy(lm) %>% 
  slice(2) # pull specific coefficient
```

Giving you a row of your data frame for a and x:

```
# A tibble: 1 × 6
  response term  estimate std.error statistic p.value
  <chr>    <chr>    <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>   <dbl>
1 a        x       -0.586     0.538     -1.09   0.318
```